# What is the meaning of the word 数独 (sudoku)?

Tags: word-choice

I know that the term is used for a puzzle using the numbers 1-9, but I am unable to ascertain the meaning of the word. I was able to translate as number and Germany, but it doesn't seem right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, it's called "Sudoku" in English, and pronounced approximately as 「サドーク」. See the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku

You want to know where the meaning comes from? It's "number" (数) plus "lone/unique/single" (独), meaning that there is a unique number which fits in each square.